# Match number or an exact string

Tags: regex

In this way:

```
/(.*?)###(.\d*)###(.*?)$/is
```

I can find something like `###7680###`, but I want to match also the exact string `###gallery###`.

How would I do this it with a regular expression?

Comment: Your regex matches ################################. Do you care why, or are you looking to match specific stuff? Give all examples you want to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a pattern like this:

```
/###(\d+|gallery)###/is
```

This will match `###`, followed by one or more digits or the string `gallery`, captured in group 1, followed by `###`.

Note that the case insensitive flag (`i`) means that this would also match `###GaLlErY###`. If this is a problem, just drop the `i` at the end.